# Does Bloomberg blpapi support pagination in instrumentListRequest?

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm trying to get instrument list using `instrumentListRequest`. However, the maximum number of the results from the response is always 1000 even if I've set the request parameter `maxResult` to a number larger than 1000 (I guess this is the restriction enforced on their server side).

Does blpapi supports pagination so that I can make multiple smaller requests or any other querying technique to narrow down the results? Then I can later aggregate results from all the smaller requests to get the final results I want.

I looked up in the documentation and the provided demo `SecurityLookupExample.py` from [their GitHub](https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python/tree/master/examples/demoapps), and the only filters provided in `instrumentListRequest` are `yellowKeyFilter` and `languageOverride`, which don't do much effort in narrowing down the searching scope.

#### Update

Here is how I set the `query` and `maxResult` to the request:

```py
session = blpapi.Session()
if not session.start():
    print("Failed to start session.")
    exit()

if not session.openService("//blp/instruments"):
    print("Failed to open //blp/instruments")
    exit()

service = session.getService("//blp/instruments")
request = service.createRequest("instrumentListRequest")

request.set("query", "VN EQUITY")
request.set("maxResults", 2000)
session.sendRequest(request)
```

However, I get only 1000 results even if I set the `maxResult` to 2000. Also, it seems like the query **"VN EQUITY"** will search for securities contain **"VN"** and **"EQUITY"** not **"VN EQUITY"** with the space.

Comment: What is your query that generates > 1000 results? What type of securities? If you only ask for 50 do you get 50 or 1000? (ie is the `maxResult` parameter having an effect?)

Comment: @DS_London I added my query in the post.
Yes, the `maxResult` parameter works effectively, and it will get 50 in this case. But it seems like there is a limit of 1000 on the number of results that API can respond.

Comment: Setting the `yellowKeyFilter` to `YK_FILTER_EQTY` will restrict the search to equities, but even then you get more than 1000 results, and not necessarily what you want. Do I understand that you are trying to find all equities with the `VN` (Vietnam) exchange code (of which there are 6711 it seems)?

Comment: You could try an alternative approach, by finding the stocks traded on the Ho Chi Minh exchange, via the bulk data service (BDS in Excel) with ticker `VNINDEX Index` and the bulk data field `INDX_MWEIGHT_PX`.